# R Shiny: How can I reference reactive elements in renderUI through uiOutput() in server function?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to get one UI element to react with another, and then test to see if the first element is equal to one particular value.  I seem to be able to print out the value of the reactive element, but I cannot use it in an if statement to check its value.  Code is below.  I have commented out the troublesome part around line 23.  It runs with the lines commented out, and verifies that the reactive element input$paramRes1 does have an character value of an integer between 1 - 5, as expected, but when I un-comment out the lines to check if that integer value is 1, it tells me that input$paramRes1 is null.  The exact error is:

```
Warning:
Error in if: argument is of length zero
Stack trace (innermost first):
59: observerFunc [#16]
 4: <Anonymous>
 3: do.call
 2: print.shiny.appobj
 1: <Promise>
```

Why would it tell me that input$paramRes1 is null, when it prints out as an char?  Or am I misreading the error?  Thanks for your help!

```
suppressWarnings(library(shiny))
suppressWarnings(library(shinyFiles))
    ui <- function(request) {
    fluidPage(
        uiOutput("param1"),
        uiOutput("param2"),
        fluidRow(column(12, verbatimTextOutput("value", placeholder = T)))
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    state = reactiveValues()

    observe({
          state$choice <- setNames(as.list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), c("First", "Second",
            "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth"))
    })
    output$param1 <- renderUI({
        selectInput("paramRes1", "Select Param 1", state$choice, selected = 1)
    })
    output$param2 <- renderUI({
        textInput("paramNm", "Param", value = input$paramRes1, width = '150px')
    })

    observe({
      #  if (input$paramRes1 %in% 1) {
            state$val <- input$paramRes1
      #  } else {
      #      state$val <- 0
      #  }

    })

    output$value <- renderText({ str(state$val) })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Could you please edit your code so that your example code is reproducible? I note that wherever you have `state$"var"` it should be called as a function `state()$"var"` ...that may have nothing to do with your issues, but you haven't included enough for us to work with

Comment: In shiny, `input` variables always are initialized with the value `NULL` so your server logic should be able to handle that. Using `observeEvent` instead of `observe` works for your example since `observeEvent` ignores nulls by default.

Comment: When I change it to observeEvent() via     observeEvent(input$paramRes1, {
        if (input$paramRes1 %in% "1") {
            state$val <- "It's 1"
        } else {
            state$val <- "It's not 1"
        }                                                                                                                                          , state$val never changes from initial "It's not 1" to  "It's 1", even when it is changed in the UI back to "1".

Comment: Am I misusing obeserveEvent() in this way, expecting that while input$paramRes1 initializes to NULL, changes in the value of input$paramRes1 (via changes in UI) should cause the re-evaluation of the condition of (input$paramRes1 %in% "1") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a (slightly) simplified version of your app with the fix I suggested in the comments

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("param1"),
  uiOutput("param2"),
  fluidRow(column(12, verbatimTextOutput("value", placeholder = T)))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  state = reactiveValues(choice = list(
    first = 1, second = 2, third = 3, fourth = 4, fifth = 5
  ))
  output$param1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("paramRes1", "Select Param 1", state$choice, selected = 1)
  })
  output$param2 <- renderUI({
    textInput("paramNm", "Param", value = input$paramRes1, width = '150px')
  })
  observeEvent(input$paramRes1,{
    if (input$paramRes1 %in% 1)
      state$val <- "It's 1"
    else
      state$val <- "It's not 1"
  })
  output$value <- renderText({ state$val })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You're welcome. TBH, I'm puzzled that the "quickfix" I recommended in the comments did not work for you, but this solution does. My guess is you misspelled `input$paramRes1` somewhere.

Comment: Actually, I simply added quotes to  if (input$paramRes1 %in% "1") by mistake.  Once I removed the quotes, it worked as you suggested it would.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work? I'm only changing the server portion here. The difference is highlighted in between `######`.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  state = reactiveValues()

  observe({
    state$choice <- setNames(as.list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), c("First", "Second",
                                                      "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth"))
   })
  output$param1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("paramRes1", "Select Param 1", state$choice, selected = 1)
  })
  output$param2 <- renderUI({
    textInput("paramNm", "Param", value = input$paramRes1, width = '150px')
  })

#####
  observeEvent(input$paramRes1, {
     if (input$paramRes1 == 1) {
     state$val <- input$paramRes1
      } else {
     state$val <- 0
      }
  })
###### 

   output$value <- renderText({ str(state$val) })
 }
```